# Dynamic Data population in Table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am very new to this IOS development. I am trying to get the Data dynamically from webservice to populate the Data in Table view so that it will be displayed like a Grid. Can Any one help me step by step or with an example so that I can proceed further. Main thing here is I an using storyboard and `UINavigationController`.

Comment: have u populated a table using static data

Comment: No I dont have any idea on this

Comment: What format of data are you getting from webservices, JSON? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Getting JSON Data from webservice Genie

Comment: then, first go through some tutorials to create table using static values. Then, u can try using dynamic values

Comment: Chandru I tried lo load the static Data with the help of identifier and that is done from y side

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tutorials.

[How to populate a tableView from the web](http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-16-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web/)

But maybe you need to begin for How to work with services

[consuming REST Services](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-ios/)

And your best friend here is the official documentation
[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/).

Here is a link to apple site that has a very good discussion about [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html). Try to read it nicely it will help. Don't worry about JSON data if you know how UITableView works then you can find a way to display the JSON data in tableview. Here is a pretty good [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) how it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should better check for some step by step tutorial and get a basic idea. Here is some links which you can start off:

[Storyboard tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[Loading data from server in UITableview](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[AFNetworking crash course](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course)

Hope this helps! Happy Coding.